# Django ORM query against data month, day, year?

Tags: django, datetime, orm

So, I know I can use __lte and __gte filters on object dates using the Django ORM as so:

```
events = Event.objects.all().order_by('start_date').filter(
    start_date__lte=_day, end_date__gte=_day
)
```

I can also query against date components:

```
events = Event.objects.all().order_by('start_date').filter(
    start_date__day=_day.day, end_date__day=_day.day
)
```

but what I'm trying to figure out is *can I query against specific parts of the date AND also use the gte and lte operators*, such as the following attempt that **doesn't** work:

```
events = Event.objects.all().order_by('start_date').filter(
    start_date__day__lte=8, end_date__day__gte=_day
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't.

Long(er) answer:

In this case I'd create a method on the manager, and use either `.extra(where='...')` (which would probably require DB-specific SQL code) or a combination of `models.Q` objects on the `Event` queryset.

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def day_range(self, start, end):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        qs = qs.extra(where=["day(start_date) < %s and day(end_date) > %s"],
                      params=[start, end])
        return qs
```

*Edited: the `where` arg had to be a sequence.*

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've declared the manager in my models.py, and set objects = EventManager on the Event model. When I try to use events = Event.objects.day_range(1,28).all() as a test in a view somewhere, I can see the SQL isn't getting executed (using debug-toolbar). Any tips on getting it to execute?

Comment: I ended up getting it working by setting the where=[".."] instead of where="". Now I have to figure out how to get it working for the real example not just the simple one I gave :)

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I wrote out from memory... Will edit to correct it. Happy to be helpful.